# Hiding Profiles and Entity Data on Exposed API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, spring-security

I am relatively new to spring boot, and recently, I noticed that going to my URL API will allow anyone to access all my entities and entity profiles.

For example going to `api.example.com/exampleEntity` (replace example.com with my personal site) will list all entities that exist in my DB, and going to `api.example.com/profile/exampleEntity` will display all of the outputs. Furthermore, going to `api.example.com` will show a output like this:

```
    {
  "_links" : {
    "testEntities" : {
      "href" : "http://*redacted*:8080/testEntities"
    }
  }
}
```

Now obviously, I don't need to state why that might be a bad idea. How do we hide this, and are there any other exposed endpoints that spring opens that I should know about?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When declaring your repository, use the annotation

```
 @RestRepositoryResource(exported = false)
```

instead of `@RestRepositoryResource`. This will hide your entities and all direct links to them from being exposed.